# How to read Hexadecimal value from registry string

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 Project to check one Hexadecimal Value from Registry Key **MyCompanyName\1**. If the **Hexadecimal Value** is **13**, then some message will be there else some other message will be there.
[image: MyProject]

So I have defined the following codes:

```
procedure TMainForm.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistryEntry : TRegistry;
begin
  RegistryEntry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  RegistryEntry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if (RegistryEntry.KeyExists('SOFTWARE\MyCompanyName\1\')) then
    begin
      if (RegistryEntry.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\MyCompanyName\1\',true)) then
        begin
          if (RegistryEntry.ReadString('SettingValue') = '0x00000013')  then
            begin
              Memo01.Lines.Add('SettingHexadeciamlValue exist properly')
            end
          else
            begin
              Memo01.Lines.Add('SettingHexadeciamlValue does not exist properly')
            end;
        end
      else
        begin
          if (RegistryEntry.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\MyCompanyName\1\',false)) then
            begin
              Memo01.Lines.Add('Unable to read RegistryKey ''MyCompanyName''Exiting.......')
            end;
        end;

    end
  else
    begin
      Memo01.Lines.Add('RegistryKey ''MyCompanyName'' does not exist')
    end;
end;
```

After compilation, when I am running the application **AsAdministrator**, I am getting error mentioning **Invalid data type for 'SettingValue'**.

Comment: You don't need to to run as admin to read, you don't want to pass `True` to `OpenKey`, you would be better calling `OpenKeyReadOnly`. The answer to your question is found in the `Caption` of the regedit dialog you showed. It's a `DWORD`!

Comment: You have a serious memory leak in your code. You never free the `TRegistry` object. Use `try..finally`.

Comment: Though I know very well that this is not a **String** but an **Integer** yet I called it because there is no function as Registry.ReadHex('').

Comment: I will certainly free registry by calling **RegistryEntry.CloseKey()** and **RegistryEntry.Free** at final stage, but not shown in sample code.

Comment: In which case you can't pay enough attention to Andreas's list of textual representations of things that all mean 62. There's a really important lesson in there and Andreas has explained it beautifully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These values are integers, not strings, so you should use `ReadInteger`, not `ReadString`.

Now, hexadecimal is only a way of *presenting* an integer to the user, that is, a method of creating a 'textual representation' of the integer. For example, the integer 62 has many different textual representations:

```
62 (decimal)
LXII (Roman numerals)
3E (hexadecimal)
111110 (binary)
Sextiotvå (Swedish words)
```

etc.

If you want to display this number in hexadecimal, as the registry editor (`regedit.exe`) does, you can use the `IntToHex` function, which creates a hexadecimal textual representation of the argument integer. Example:

```
var
  myvalue: integer;

...

myvalue := ReadInteger('SettingValue');
ShowMessage(IntToHex(myvalue, 8));
```

Comment: Again my account has been get locked displaying **Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account**. Administrator please unlock my account.